# PostgreSQL query not using INDEX when RLS (Row Level Security) is enabled

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, row-level-security

I am using **PostgreSQL 10.1**, going right to the point...

Lets say I have a **TABLE**:

```
CREATE TABLE public.document (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,

    title   text,
    content text NOT NULL
);
```

Together with a **GIN INDEX** on it:

```
CREATE INDEX document_idx ON public.document USING GIN(
    to_tsvector(
        'english',
        content || ' ' || COALESCE(title, '')
    )
);
```

And a basic fulltext search query:

```
SELECT * FROM public.document WHERE (
    to_tsvector(
        'english',
        content || ' ' || COALESCE(title, '')
    ) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', fulltext_search_documents.search_text)
)
```

Regardless of the **public.document** table size, the query is (you already know it) hella fast! The planner uses the INDEX and everything works out great.

Now I introduce some basic access control through **RLS (Row Level Security)**, firstly I enable it:

```
ALTER TABLE public.document ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

and then I add the policy:

```
CREATE POLICY document_policy ON public.document FOR SELECT
    USING (EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM public.user WHERE (is_current_user) AND ('r' = ANY(privileges))
    ));
```

To keep things simple the **is_current_user** is another query which checks exactly that.

Now the **fulltext search query** is flattened with **document_policy query** and by doing so the planner executes a **Seq Scan** instead of **Index Scan** resulting in a 300x slower query!

I think the question is pretty obvious, how can I fix this so that the fulltext search query stays fast?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is a know limitation of RLS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have solved this from the time of posting... Anyone facing this issue, this is how I did it:

My solution was to have a **private** `SECURITY DEFINER` "wrapper" function containing the propper query and another **public** function which calls the **private** one and `INNER JOINS` the table which requires access control.

So in the specific case above, it would be something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION private.filter_document() RETURNS SETOF public.document AS
$$
    SELECT * FROM public.document WHERE (
        to_tsvector(
            'english',
            content || ' ' || COALESCE(title, '')
        ) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', fulltext_search_documents.search_text)
    )
$$
LANGUAGE SQL STABLE SECURITY DEFINER;
----
CREATE FUNCTION public.filter_document() RETURNS SETOF public.document AS
$$
    SELECT filtered_d.* FROM private.filter_documents() AS filtered_d
        INNER JOIN public.document AS d ON (d.id = filtered_d.id)
$$
LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Since I was using [Postgraphile](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/introduction/) (which is **super awesome** BTW!), I was able to omit introspection of the **private** schema, making the "dangerous" function inaccessible! With proper security implementations, the end-user will only see the final GraphQL schema, complately removing **Postgres** from the outside world.

This worked beautifly! <del>Until recently when **Postgres 10.3**  was released and fixed it, dropping the need for this hack.</del>

On the other hand, my RLS policies are very complex, nested and go really deep. The tables which they are run agains are also quite large (roughly 50,000+ entries to run RLS against in total). Even with super complex and nested policies, I managed to maintain the performance within reasonable boundries.

When working with RLS, keep in mind the following:

1. Create proper `INDEXES`
2. **Prefer inline queries everywhere**! (Even if that means rewriting the same query N times)
3. Avoid functions in policies by all means! If you absolutely must have them inside, make sure that they are `STABLE` and have a high `COST` (like @mkurtz pointed out); or are `IMMUTABLE`
4. Extract the query from the policy, run it directly with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and try optimizing it as much as possible

Hope you guys find the information helpful as much as I did!

Answer (score 1):

Try following:
Instead of writing the query into the `USING(...)` clause put the query into a `STABLE` function with a very high cost.
By doing so the function should not be called very often now - ideally only once per query lifetime, because the cost of calling the function seems now very high to Postgres. Marking the function as `STABLE` tells Postgres that the result of the function doesn't change during a single query lifetime. I think that is correct for your query, isn't it?
Read more about about this two parameters [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createfunction.html).

Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_permission () RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
    SELECT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM public.user WHERE (is_current_user) AND ('r' = ANY(privileges))
    )
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE COST 100000;
```

And the policy now:

```
CREATE POLICY document_policy ON public.document FOR SELECT
    USING (check_permission());
```

Hopefully this will give you better performance. But be aware, this only works correctly if it is OK to mark the function as `STABLE`. If your function could return different results during a single query lifetime then this wouldn't work correctly and you would end up with weird results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mkurz! I knew about the COST "hack", which is fine when you need small portions for the policies. However (as of Postgres 10.3+ at least) in the example above, it is again more effective to use the inline query (regarding this specific case). And yeah, I need my policies to be super dynamic, so a single high cost function wont work.

Comment: But on the other hand, I have solved this from the time of posting. My solution was to have a **private** `SECURITY DEFINER` "wrapper" function containing the query and another **public** function which calls the **private** one and `INNER JOINS` the table which require access control.

Comment: @enisdenjo Interesting! Could you update your question with your solution including sql snippets (or at another answer)? I am also interested in row level security for our next application and find your approach interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @mkurz, you can find an explanation and an example in my answer. Hope it helps you!

Comment: @enisdenjo Great! Thank you very much - I appreciate that you took the time to write this down :)